# Building msbuild 15 project programmatically

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I'm trying to build a simple C# 7 class library project created with VS2017.

MSBuild from framework assemblies is outdated, so I'm referencing `Microsoft.Build`, `Microsoft.Build.Engine` and `Microsoft.Build.Framework` from MSBuild folder within visual studio (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`).

Still, when I do this:

```cs
using (var collection = new ProjectCollection())
{
    var proj = collection.LoadProject(@"c:\projects\Sample\Sample.csproj"); // <-- exception
    proj.Build(new[] {new ConsoleLogger()});
}
```

I'm getting `InvalidProjectFileException: The tools version "15.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "4.0", "2.0".`

Is there programmatic way to invoke build using the latest build tools and C# 7 compiler?

Comment: How are you invoking MSBuild?  It sounds like you're still invoking the 4.0 version installed with Windows, not the 15.0 version installed with VS2017.

Comment: @Jimmy I'm referencing above-mentioned assemblies from MSBuild folder within VS2017 installation. Within Modules debugging window in VS I can see that the right versions (15.1) load up. I either reference them with "Copy Local" set to true, or adding a custom handler to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` to point resolution to the MSBuild folder itself. In either case there's no toolset version 15 available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar needs for my team and I wrote a Builder library for C# that supports several versions of Visual Studio.
I could not make the Project.Build function work properly, so I went for executing MsBuild.exe directly.

How I built it:

### Use Microsoft.Build.Framework from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Framework/)

### Create a new Project object with 1 target called Build

### Define the right ToolsVersion

Of the Project according to the Visual Studio version:

- 2010, 2012 => 4.0
- 2013 => 12.0
- 2015 => 14.0
- 2017 => 15.0

### Add a new task of type MsBuild

With Projects property containing all the project I need to build

### Define the ToolsVersion

of the MsBuild task with same value as for the Project

### Serialize the Project into a temporary file

### Find the right MsBuild.exe according to the ToolsVersion

## 4.0, 12.0, 14.0

Found in the registry:

```
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey($@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\{msBuildVersion}")
```

## 15.0

Not anymore in the registry, you need to use the Nuget package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.Interop](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.Interop/)

```
        var query = new SetupConfiguration();

        var query2 = (ISetupConfiguration2)query;

        var e = query2.EnumAllInstances();

        var helper = (ISetupHelper)query;

        int fetched;

        var instances = new ISetupInstance[1];

        do
        {
            e.Next(1, instances, out fetched);
            if (fetched > 0)
            {
                var instance = instances[0];

                var instance2 = (ISetupInstance2)instance;

                var state = instance2.GetState();

                // Skip non-complete instance, I guess?
                // Skip non-local instance, I guess?
                // Skip unregistered products?
                if (state != InstanceState.Complete
                    || (state & InstanceState.Local) != InstanceState.Local
                    || (state & InstanceState.Registered) != InstanceState.Registered)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var msBuildComponent =
                    instance2.GetPackages()
                        .FirstOrDefault(
                            p =>
                                p.GetId()
                                    .Equals("Microsoft.Component.MSBuild",
                                        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

                if (msBuildComponent == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var instanceRootDirectory = instance2.GetInstallationPath();

                var msbuildPathInInstance = Path.Combine(instanceRootDirectory, "MSBuild", msBuildVersion, "Bin", "msbuild.exe");

                if (File.Exists(msbuildPathInInstance))
                {
                    return msbuildPathInInstance;
                }
            }
        } while (fetched > 0);
```

### Execute MsBuild.exe

And build the serialized Project using a custom XML Logger - you can use the one provided by [MsBuildExtensionPack](https://github.com/mikefourie/MSBuildExtensionPack)

### Read the result summary

Deserialize the result summary from Xml and use it to determine if build failed or not, which errors and warnings occurred etc.

Comment: What's the purpose of getting the `Microsoft.Build.Framework` NuGet package in the beginning if you're still looking for the MSBuild.exe installed with VS and invoke that later on?

Comment: This package allows you to define MsBuild project files using their model, then serialize it in a file and use MsBuild.exe to run it. The runner provided in the libraries is limited compared to MsBuild.exe. I cannot tell anymore what are the limitations though...

Comment: Aah, I see. I had found this question based on the situation that I already have a `.csproj` file (and could do the few changes that might be needed by some Xml manipulation), so I was a bit confused why that NuGet package was required if not for actually building.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same issues in my project.
In my case I want to build an SSDT project programmatically but I tried other project types as well.

Interestingly, it worked perfectly fine in build 26228.04 of VS2017 (which was the Release build) and stopped working in build 26228.09.
Yesterday build 26228.10 was released, so I decided to give it another go.

Surprisingly the following worked for me:

1. Update to the latest VS2017 build 26228.10 using the Visual Studio Installer.
2. I was never able to get `collection.LoadProject(...)` to work without getting some weird error but you can use this code to do the build:

   ```
   BuildResult result = null;

   using (var pc = new ProjectCollection())
       result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(
           new BuildParameters(pc) { Loggers = new[] { new ConsoleLogger() } },
           // Change this path to your .sln file instead of the .csproj.
           // (It won't work with the .csproj.)
           new BuildRequestData(@"c:\projects\Sample.sln",
               // Change the parameters as you need them,
               // e.g. if you want to just Build the Debug (not Rebuild the Release).
               new Dictionary<string, string>
               {
                   { "Configuration", "Release" },
                   { "Platform", "Any CPU" }
               }, null, new[] { "Rebuild" }, null));

   if (result.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Failure)
       // Something bad happened...
   ```
3. Ensure that you have copied all the MSBuild assembly binding redirections to your `.config` file.
   If you haven't already done this, open the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe.config` and copy the whole `<runtime>` element to the `<configuration>` element of your own `.config` file in the project that uses MSBuild programmatically.
   If you don't redirect the MSBuild assembly versions, you will get some pretty strange error messages from MSBuild which will vary based on your MSBuild version.
   But it's sure to say: It will definitely not work without the assembly binding redirections.
4. One additional step if you want to build an SSDT project:
   Change the following two lines in your `.sqlproj` file from

   ```
   <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
   <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(SSDTExists)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">15.0</VisualStudioVersion>
   <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(SSDTExists)' == ''">15.0</VisualStudioVersion>
   ```

I'm not 100% sure why, but these steps worked perfectly for me!
But because MSBuild is a bit "difficult" to use programmatically (in my opinion it's sometimes as stable as a weather forecast), chances are that my approach won't work in your case.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need the path to the latest MSBuild.exe, use **Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core** from Nuget and use the following code:

```
ToolLocationHelper.GetPathToBuildToolsFile("msbuild.exe", ToolLocationHelper.CurrentToolsVersion);
```

This works whether just Build Tools are installed or the full Visual Studio installation.

Comment: @Konrad Make sure you are using the latest VS 2017 and Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core. There was an issue in VS 2017 some versions back which prevented this from working.

Comment: I'm using the latest VS 2017 and the latest Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core. I'm running it in .NET Core 2.1 project.

Comment: The .NET Core version of msbuild has .dll extension though, it doesn't appear to work anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is already solved in a PreRelease version ([15.5.0-preview-000072-0942130](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2369#issuecomment-324676752)) of msbuild, see MsBuild issue [#2369: msbuild nuget package unable to open vs2017 csproj files](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2369).
So in future no further hacks needed

Answer (score 0):

This is easier now, since Microsoft has released their own package.

Set up package references [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/updating-an-existing-application?view=vs-2019#use-nuget-packages-preferred). Note the `ExcludeAssets="runtime"` on all packages except for the Locator package:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.4.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build" Version="16.10.0" ExcludeAssets="runtime" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" Version="16.10.0" ExcludeAssets="runtime" />
```

```cs
public Init()
{
    MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();
    var project = LoadProject(@"C:\Path\To\Project.csproj");
}

public Project LoadProject(string csprojPath)
{
    var context = new ProjectCollection();
    return context.LoadProject(csprojPath);
}
```

According to the documentation link above, the call to the Microsoft.Build assemblies needs to happen in a different method than the `MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults()`.