# Programmatically building c# projects with C# version 6 and 7 code gives compile errors

Tags: compilation, msbuild, c#-6.0, c#-7.0

I want to compile a target project programmatically by using

```
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Build()
```

If my target project that needs to be compiled contains `C#` 6.0 features like the safe navigation operator (`?.` Operator) it gives errors exactly on these lines of code.
If I remove these lines of code in my target project it compiles fine.

Does anyone have any idea how to compile `C#` 6.0 and 7.0 style code  programmatically?
In the project that builds my runtime version of the build `Microsoft.Build.dll` is v4.0.30319 and the `.Net` framework version is 4.6.2.

I added two simple projects. The first console project is the code that compiles. The second console project is the target project to be compiled. By commenting out line 15, the compilation successful, otherwise the logfile shows errors on that line.

The project that compiles

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Build.Logging;


namespace CompilerApp
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string projectfile = @"C:\temp\CompilerApp\MyCSharp7\MyCSharp7.csproj";

        UnloadAnyProject();
        Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project p = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(projectfile);
        FileLogger loggerfile2 = new FileLogger();
        loggerfile2.Parameters = @"logfile=C:\temp\CompilerApp\myapp.msbuild.log";
        bool buildresult = p.Build(loggerfile2);
        if (buildresult)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("project compiled");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("project not compiled, check {0}", @"C:\temp\myapp.msbuild.log");

        }
        p.Save();
        UnloadAnyProject();
    }

    private static void UnloadAnyProject()
    {
        Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projcoll = Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection;

        foreach (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project pr in projcoll.LoadedProjects)
        {
            Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection mypcollection = pr.ProjectCollection;
            mypcollection.UnloadProject(pr);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The targetproject that should be compiled:

```
using System;
namespace MyCSharp7
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("truncate {0}", Truncate("Hello", 3));
    }

    public static string Truncate(string value, int length)
    {
        //csharp 6/7
        //comment out line below for succesfull compilation
        return value?.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, length));

        // csharp<6
        string result = value;
        if (value != null) // Skip empty string check for elucidation
        {
            result = value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, length));
        }
        return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if it doesn't exist in 7.0, there is a good chance there is a good reason for it. Consider reading up on why it is no longer there

Comment: It's not about features that don't exist anymore, it's about features that  are newly added in the versions c# 6.0 like the ?. Operator and the nameof() operator.

Comment: Have you tried using `Microsoft.Build` from NuGet?

Comment: I tried it. it got from bad to worse. I installed 15.1.548
Now I get an error when loading the projectfile 
Project p = new Project(projectfile);

MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: Type information for Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper was present in the whitelist cache as Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper, Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a but the type could not be loaded. unexpectedly null

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround.

In the references of your compiling project do not use the standard .net assemblies of Microsoft.Build and Microsoft.Build.Framework.
Let the references to Microsoft.Build and Microsoft.Build.Framework point to the corresponding dll's in the building engine that are installed with the installation of Visual Studio instead.

In a default installation of f.i. VS2017 the building engine is located in :
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\

so add the references in the project that builds by picking Microsoft.Build.dll and the Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll from there

This workaround doesn't solve the problem mentioned above. I think the problem is caused that the .Net Microsoft Build libraries never have been reprogrammed since the introduction of C# 6 and 7

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49992566/253938 for a possible way to "automate" the referencing of the MSBuild components that are installed with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you install [`MS Build` 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48159) (or from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15)), you'll see the `15.0` folder on your disk, after that use that `exe`-file, problem should be resolved (worked for me).

Comment: @WMAtm Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I  won't check this solution because the workaround mentioned above is working and with your solution I am forced installing extra VS2015 parts in a system with only a VS2017 installation. Just preventing trouble like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078438/building-msbuild-15-project-programmatically?rq=1)